# colorbox iframe as modal : how to return true/false to parent

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, colorbox

i find it's bit rare to find documentation of using colorbox as modal box.
anyway i do iframe technique as modal dialog, so in my parent's page, the js is like this :

```
    $(".confirmDeleteUser").colorbox({
        onOpen: function () {
            $("#colorbox").addClass("standardLightbox");
        },
        onLoad: function () {
            $('#cboxClose').remove();
        },
        iframe: true,
        href: "/modal_yesno.html",
        innerWidth: "530",
        innerHeight: "400", 
        fixed: true, 
        overlayClose: false
    });
```

the html of parent page is something like this :

```
<a href="deleteuser.php?id=2" class="confirmDeleteUser">Delete user</a>
```

and for the `modal_yesno.html` is like this:

```
        $('.buttonNo').click(function () {
            return false;
            parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
        });

        $('.buttonYes').click(function () {
            return true;
            parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();                
        });
```

but the modal is not closed, and the return value is not sent to parent.

so the question is how to send the true/false javascript to the parent and close the colorbox right after?

Answer (score 2):

The return value wouldn't be sent back to the parent window, it would be sent back to the element that triggered the event; the button.

I think the following should work:

```
$('.buttonNo').click(function () {
   parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
   window.parent.Confirmation(false);
});

$('.buttonYes').click(function () {
   parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();   
   window.parent.Confirmation(true);
});
```

Where Confirmation() is a method in your parent page.

Comment: i succeeded call parent's function and it return the value correct. but it doesnt call the href in the parent even though it return true..